# параллельные запросы

Tags: java, android, rxjava, rxandroid

Добрый день, помогите неучу с подобной задачкой.

Есть N запросов до сервера, они не зависимы друг для друга, поэтому есть желание выполнить их параллельно. Вопрос в том как их правильно организовать.
Сейчас я делаю для каждого из них флаги и проверяю все ли корректно отработало, и по итогу ставлю результат.

Выглядит как-то так:

```
private void loadDataFromServer() {
    loadUserInfo();
    loadProfileInfo();
}

private void loadUserInfo() {
    Subscription subscription = mService.getUserMe()
            .compose(Utils.applySchedulers())
            .subscribe(userModel -> {
                        UserDataUtils.setUserInfo(userModel);
                        isUserInfoLoaded = true;
                        checkLoadFinished();
                    },
                    throwable ->
                            isSuccess = false);

    unsubscribeOnDestroy(subscription);
}

private void loadProfileInfo() {
    Subscription subscription = mService.getProfileInfo()
            .compose(Utils.applySchedulers())
            .subscribe(accountInfoModel -> {
                        isProfileInfoLoaded = true;

                        UserDataUtils.setAccountInfo(accountInfoModel);

                        checkLoadFinished();
                    },
                    throwable ->
                            isSuccess = false);

    unsubscribeOnDestroy(subscription);
}

private void checkLoadFinished() {
    if (isSuccess) {
        if (isUserInfoLoaded && isProfileInfoLoaded) {
            loadSuccess();
        }
    } else {
        loadFailed();
    }
}

private void loadSuccess() {
    getViewState().showBaseFragment();
    getViewState().hideProgressDialog();
    getViewState().blockNavigation(false);
    getViewState().updateNavigationMenu();
}

private void loadFailed() {
    getViewState().blockNavigation(true);
    getViewState().showError(R.string.error_no_internet_connection);
    getViewState().hideProgressDialog();
}
```

Т.к. при увеличении запросов появляется копипаста, то уверен, что можно сделать красиво, но не знаю как.

Коллеги поделитесь опытом с новичком, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подобные решения легко можно найти.
Если в кратко, то делать надо так
 `Observable.zip(observable1,observable2,observable3,Func)`
Если необходимо обработать результат каждого отдельно, то можно предварительно сделать так `observableN.doOnNext()`

ЗЫ: сабжекты не вздумайте использовать для такого.

Comment: Раскройте про сабжекты, а то как-то очень субъективно получается

Comment: @andreich Спасибо, и я вот смотрю ответ ниже сразу противоречит вашему, пожалуйста можно чуть подробнее.

Comment: Subject в данном случае предполагает хранение состояний в глобальной переменной, хранение состояний несет сложности и потенциальные баги, это если по ответу ниже. Вообще, если нет понимания, что такое subject, то лучше стараться избегать их использования, иначе можно получить трудно воспроизводимые проблемы. Есть ситуации, когда без них не обойтись, но не в данном случае. Поэтому надо либо изучить, либо не трогать.

Answer (score 0):

```
public PublishSubject<Boolean> progress = PublishSubject.create();
```

Перед запуском запросов:

```
progress
    .take(3)
    .all(result -> result)
    .subscribe(result -> {
        if (result){
            loadSuccess();
        } else loadFailed();
    });
```

В каждом запросе

```
progress.next(true)
```

Или

```
progress.next(false)
```

ЗЫ писал по памяти, так что возможно придется напильником доработать